# PHPExcel $objDrawing Fatal Error

Tags: phpexcel

I'm trying to open xlsx file ([link](https://trimet.ru/download/files/Trimet%20price.xlsx)), but get fatal error

> Fatal error: Call to a member function attributes() on a non-object in
>   PHPExcel/Reader/Excel2007.php on line 1509

line 1509:

```
$objDrawing->setWidth(PHPExcel_Shared_Drawing::EMUToPixels(self::array_item($xfrm->ext->attributes(), "cx")));
```

If delete this row with $xfrm variable error does not appear.

For PHPExcel developers:

Below is the condition `if( $xfrm )`, maybe you need to include the 
problematic line in the condition?

```
$objDrawing->setWidth(PHPExcel_Shared_Drawing::EMUToPixels(self::array_item($xfrm->ext->attributes(), "cx")));                                      
$objDrawing->setHeight(PHPExcel_Shared_Drawing::EMUToPixels(self::array_item($xfrm->ext->attributes(), "cy")));
if ($xfrm) {
    $objDrawing->setRotation(PHPExcel_Shared_Drawing::angleToDegrees(self::array_item($xfrm->attributes(), "rot")));
}
```

Comment: It does raise the question of why `$xfrm->ext` doesn't have any attributes

Comment: Mark, I don't know, maybe file have an error or something else (although I can open it in MS Office without problems). But it would be nice if PHPExcel not lead to fatal errors if they can be avoided.